# Using Wordpress Custom Fields to Color background posts

Tags: wordpress, colors, background, field

i am trying to use the custom fields within wordpress to make different background colors for each post kind of like this [website here](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights)

as of right now on my localhost, as a test i have the custom field name as abc123 and then the value as yellow

and here is the code:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Check out our blog</h2>
                <hr class="light">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center" >
                    <?php
// Get the last 3 posts.
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
$bgcolor1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, "abc123", true);
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    <div style="background-color:<?php echo $bgcolor1; ?>">
                        <h2 class="section-heading">
                            <a class="link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to 
                                <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </h2>
                        <p>
                            <?php the_excerpt();?>
                        </p>
                        <a class="link" href="
                            <?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Read More!</a>
                        <hr class="blight">
                        </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

its doing all the posts as the latest color added from latest post, wondering how to fix that

also its showing the colors on my localhost webserver but not online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had removed the line

```
$bgcolor1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, "abc123", true);
```

and also the echo of $bgcolor1

```
<div style="background-color:<?php echo $bgcolor1; ?>">
```

and replaced it with

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'custom-field-name',true) ?>
```

like so

```
<div style="background-color:<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'custom-field-name',true) ?>;">
```

and it works great.

incase anyone needs to know how to fix something like this